# Contar elementos de un campo y agruparlos por otro campo en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft, microsoft-sql

Partiendo de una tabla "TablaComidas" de ejemplo en SQL Server como la siguiente:

| Id | Nombre | Comida |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jose | atun |
| 2 | Jose | pizza |
| 3 | Jose | pizza |
| 4 | Antonio | queso |
| 5 | Antonio | queso |
| 6 | Antonio | atun |
| 7 | Antonio | manzana |
| 8 | Antonio | ensalada |
| 9 | Antonio | ensalada |
| 10 | Antonio | tomate |
| 11 | Antonio | tomate |
| 12 | Maria | tomate |
| 13 | Maria | manzana |

Necesito una consulta que me diga la cantidad de comidas que comió cada persona, es decir, un resultado similar al siguiente:

| Nombre | Atun | Pizza | Queso | Tomate | Ensalada | Manzana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jose | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Antonio | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Maria | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Sólo he conseguido realizar la consulta de 1 sola persona de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
(SELECT DISTINCT(Nombre) FROM TablaComidas WHERE Nombre = 'Jose') Nombre,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as Atun FROM TablaComidas WHERE Nombre = 'Jose' AND Comida = 'Atun') Atun,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as Pizza FROM TablaComidas WHERE Nombre = 'Jose' AND Comida = 'Pizza') Pizza,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as Queso FROM TablaComidas WHERE Nombre = 'Jose' AND Comida = 'Queso') Queso,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as Tomate FROM TablaComidas WHERE Nombre = 'Jose' AND Comida = 'Tomate') Tomate,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as Ensalada FROM TablaComidas WHERE Nombre = 'Jose' AND Comida = 'Ensalada') Ensalada,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as Manzana FROM TablaComidas WHERE Nombre = 'Jose' AND Comida = 'Atun') Manzana
```

El resultado es similar a lo siguiente:

| Nombre | Atun | Pizza | Queso | Tomate | Ensalada | Manzana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jose | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Necesito obtener el mismo resultado pero de todas las personas juntas como mencioné.

Comment: Busca información sobre la cláusula PIVOT en SQL-Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque hay muchas maneras de pivotar, lo más extendido, por simpleza y eficiencia (no utilizando cursores) son estas 3 maneras.

**Escenario:**

```
Create table dbo.TablaComidas (id smallint, Nombre varchar(25), Comida varchar(25))
go
Insert into dbo.TablaComidas(id, Nombre, Comida)
values
(1  ,'Jose','atun'),
(2  ,'Jose','pizza'),
(3  ,'Jose','pizza'),
(4  ,'Antonio','queso'),
(5  ,'Antonio','queso'),
(6  ,'Antonio','atun'),
(7  ,'Antonio','manzana'),
(8  ,'Antonio','ensalada'),
(9  ,'Antonio','ensalada'),
(10 ,'Antonio','tomate'),
(11 ,'Antonio','tomate'),
(12 ,'Maria','tomate'),
(13 ,'Maria','manzana');
Go
```

***Trasponer***

```
SELECT Tc.Nombre
    , sum(case when Tc.Comida='atun' then 1 else 0 End) as Atun
    , sum(case when Tc.Comida='pizza' then 1 else 0 End)  as pizza
    , sum(case when Tc.Comida='queso' then 1 else 0 End)  as queso
    , sum(case when Tc.Comida='tomate' then 1 else 0 End) as tomate
    , sum(case when Tc.Comida='ensalada' then 1 else 0 End) as ensalada
    , sum(case when Tc.Comida='manzana' then 1 else 0 End) as manzana
    
    
FROM DBO.TablaComidas Tc
group by tc.Nombre
```

Utilizando la función Sum pero con un case interior, la suma de las veces que se menciona la comida, agrupando por Nombre.

[image: Res]

***Pivot simple***

```
Select * from
(   
    Select *
    from dbo.TablaComidas
) as source
pivot (count(id) for comida in ([atun],[pizza],[queso],[tomate],[ensalada],[manzana])) as pvt
```

[image: Res 2]

Utilizando la función pivot, puedes hacer un count del id, para y aquí lo importante cada uno de los literales, que disponga la columna comida. Este pivot, al igual que la trasposición, si tienes más alimentos, tienes que retocar la query.

***Pivot dinámico***

```
Declare @columns nvarchar(max);
Declare @query nvarchar(max);
Select @columns = 
  STUFF(
 (
 SELECT
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(Comida))
 FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT Comida
    FROM dbo.TablaComidas
   ) AS T
 ORDER BY
 Comida
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '');

 Set @query = N'
 Select * 
 fROM
 (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TablaComidas
 ) as T
 pivot (count(id) for comida in ('+@columns +N')) as pvt ';
 EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @query
```

[image: Res 3]

Evidentemente es el más complejo, pero tiene la ventaja, de que se alimentan las columnas de los diferentes valores, que pueda contener la tabla para la columna comida.

Si observas detenidamente la query, es igual que el pivot estático, pero para saber que columnas formarán parte de los literales de `for comida in (....)`, se alimenta una variable, con ellos, utilizando for xml path y stuff para poder obtener en una sola variable una lista de elementos separados por comas `[atun],[pizza] ....`

Answer (score 2):

Tal como tienes planteado el problema, lo más cómodo es usar una agregación condicional, agrupando por `Nombre` y usar un `CASE WHEN ..` para contar según `Comida`

```
SELECT Nombre,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Comida = 'Atun' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)     as 'Atun',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Comida = 'Pizza' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)    as 'Pizza',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Comida = 'Queso' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)    as 'Queso',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Comida = 'Tomate' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)   as 'Tomate',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Comida = 'Ensalada' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'Ensalada',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Comida = 'Manzana' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)  as 'Manzana'
       FROM TablaComidas
       GROUP BY Nombre
```